# Hard removal of git tags

Tags: git, tags

The porcelain command for removing tags in git is

```
git fetch <remote> --prune --tags
```

This will updated and remove any tag that is removed on the remote.

Problem is that one remote has a major amount of tags and removing them takes a huge amount of time. Therefor I have tried to just remove the tag files and it seems ok so far.

```
rm -rf .git/refs/tags/*
```

Besides the risk of losing tags that I do want, is there any side affects that I have foreseen? Does git keep any other references to the tags the will be in some kind of wrong state?

Comment: The corresponding git command is `git tag -l '*' | xargs git tag -d`. Not `git fetch` as I stated above. Infact this is fast enough for me as no network needs to be involved. I have also seen lock files under `.git/refs/tags`, so I will play it safe and stay with git porcelain commands.